# Use conditional formatting in Google Sheet to highlight scholars in different rosters (lists) from a global list of discharged scholars

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have 12 rosters of 30 scholars each.
I have a list of scholars that are being discharged.
I want to highlight any scholars that are in the 12 rosters that are on the discharge lists.

I already have conditional formatting across the 12 rosters to make sure scholars aren't put on the any rosters more than once using the following:

Custom formula

```
=countif($A$1:$G$23,A1)>1
```

Applied to range

```
A1:G22
```

To highlight scholars that are on the discharge list I used the following conditional formatting:

Custom formula

```
=countif($A$1:$I,A1)>1
```

Applied to range

```
A1:G22
```

I would like to know if anyone could figure out a better way to do this where I can select individual rosters instead of the whole area.

As a bonus it would be great to have the discharge list on a different sheet and still have the same effect.

Picture below

[Roster w Dupe & Discharge Highlights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmc7L.jpg)

Here is the file: feel free to edit the google sheet.

[Roster w/ Dupe & Discharge Highlights](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b20FQkSh1tQkO8HEV8Vt6mzFvLh4Dt6kge2Yo4VzeOM/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

try for applied range:

```
A1:G6,C9:C14
```

[image]